# Усовершенствовать код для прохождения теста на сайте

Tags: pascal

Дано два двухзначных числа. Определить, есть ли у них одинаковые цифры. Вывести YES, если одинаковые цифры есть в заданных числах и NO - в противном случае.

Входные данные:
Во входном потоке записаны через пробел два двухзначных числа. 
Пример входного файла (input.txt):
48 68

Выходные данные:
В выходной поток вывести 'YES' или 'NO'.
Пример выходного файла (output.txt):
YES

```
  var
  A, B: integer;
  a1, a2, a3, b1, b2, b3: integer;

  begin
  readln(A, B);
  writeln;
  a1 := A div 100;
  a2 := A div 10 mod 10;
  a3 := A mod 10;
  b1 := B div 100;
  b2 := B div 10 mod 10;
  b3 := B mod 10;
  if (a1 = b1) and (a1 = b2) and (a1 = b3) and 
  (a2 = b1) and (a2 = b2) and (a2 = b3) and 
  (a3 = b1) and (a3 = b2) and (a3 = b3) then 
  writeln('NO')

  else

  writeln('YES');
  end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (a1 = b1) or (a1 = b2) or (a1 = b3) or 
   (a2 = b1) or (a2 = b2) or (a2 = b3) or 
   (a3 = b1) or (a3 = b2) or (a3 = b3)
then 
    writeln('YES')
else
    writeln('NO');
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно вместо and использовать or.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int uniq(const int n, int* const digits)
{
    if (n == 0) { return 1; }
    if (++digits[n % 10] > 1) { return 0; }
    return uniq(n / 10);
}

int main(void)
{
    int digits[10];
    int a;
    for (a = 0; a < 10; a++) { digits[a] = 0; }
    int b;
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    puts(uniq(a, digits) && uniq(b, digits) ? "YES" : "NO");
    return 0;
}
```